# Valgrind on MacBook M1

Tags: c, docker, valgrind, apple-m1

I need to install **Valgrind** on my **Mac M1** for checking memory allocation in C programming language.

Is VBox best solution for me in this case if it's not possible to install it ona Mac M1? Or can I somehow achieve it using Docker?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It's explicitly not a supported platform according to valgrind.  Why do you believe this can be "fixed"?

Comment: ARM Mac OS is not listed in the supported platforms: https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html

Comment: https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos/issues/56#issuecomment-1651811069 <- recent status and what is preventing it from working

Comment: Can I somehow create Linux container in Docker and install there Valgrind?

Comment: Docker is not great. Valgrind works better on bare metal or full virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the best results if you use a machine that the Valgrind developers use the most. That means amd64 and either RedHat Linux or FreeBSD. From what I've seen IBM do a decent job of supporting s390 and POWER.

As mentioned in the comments, Louis Brunner has done some work on getting macOS support improved. I don't have any ARM based Apple hardware so I've never tested it. I have tested his code on a Intel macbook. It's in a much better state than the upstream code - for a start it builds with recent macOS and XCode versions. However there are still many major restrictions. Just to mention 2, DRD doesn't work at all and no GUI applications work.

We need more help to get Valgrind on macOS up to the level of other platforms.